# How can i put space between 2 Words

Tags: php, sql, phpword

I am Working on a Factory System.
I use PHP Word for Generate Price List from a Database
No i Need something like -> Article_Name  (5 Times Tab Space) Price
And what i have is -> Article_Name Price
How can i put the white space between the words

All my PHP Word Code is this:

```php
$image_array = array(
      "widht" => 90,
      "height" => 100
  );
  
  
  $phpWortd = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
  $phpWortd->setDefaultFontSize(24);
  $phpWortd->setDefaultFontName('calibri');
     
  $image_section = $phpWortd->addSection();
  $image_section->addImage("./formulare/kahtrin_salon.jpg", $image_array);

  $text_section = $phpWortd->addSection();


  for($i =0; $i < count($query); $i++){
    $text_section->addText($query[$i]['art_name']." ".$query[$i]['art_price']);
  
  };
  
  $saveasHTML = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWortd, "HTML");
  $saveasHTML->save("./formulare/preise.html");
}
```

I search on Google few Hours an i Read the Documentation of PHP Word a lot of times

Comment: `$text_section->addText($query[$i]['art_name']."\t\t\t\t\t".$query[$i]['art_price']);` - Is that what you mean by "5 times tab space"?

Comment: Or may be you can use 5 times &nbsp; in Tim Lewis comment.

Comment: Or `"     "` (literally 5 spaces, etc.), assuming it'll treat that as literal spaces, but hard to say what the `addText()` method does.

Comment: If the nominated duplicate page does not resolve your question, please [edit] your question to clarify what is still not right.

Comment: I have Try with "     " and "/t/t/t/t/t". In the Quellcode the Whitespace its ok but in the Live View when i goes to Print it dosent work

Comment: If i use &nbsp its ok but then the words are underordered. I need the Word one under one. I have 3 Colums (Name, Kg, price) no i need to have name under name, kg under kg etc